# Javascript Date works with temporaries but fails when first assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, parse-platform

It appears that date comparison works with temporary variables but fails when one or both dates are first assigned to a local variable.  This seems very odd to me, what could I be missing?

```
var before = Date(2012,11,9)
console.log(new Date(2012,11,10) > before)  // -> false
console.log(new Date(2012,11,10) > new Date(2012, 11, 9)) // -> true
```

I reproduced this from the Atom editor, and also on Parse, which is also on Node.js.

```
Atom Runner: hacks.js

false
true
Exited with code=0 in 0.084 seconds
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [MDN - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)  : `JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript Date as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript Date objects have no literal syntax.`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the "new" keyword when assigning the date to `before`.

Try this again using:

```
var before = new Date(2012,11,9);
```

Answer (score 2):

This produces a string

```
Date(2012,11,9)
```

This produces a Date object

```
new Date(2012,11,9)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `new` keyword. Calling the `Date` constructor without `new` [returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript Date as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript Date objects have no literal syntax.

Compare:

```
var before = Date(2012,11,9)
console.log(typeof before) // 'string'
```

vs:

```
var before = new Date(2012,11,9)
console.log(typeof before) // 'object'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, I put a new in front of the declaration for before:

```
var before = new Date(2012,11,9);
console.log(new Date(2012,11,10) > before);  
console.log(new Date(2012,11,10) > new Date(2012, 11, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

X > X is always false.
2012-11-10 is more recent than 2012-11-09. It's YYYY,MM,DD order!

Comment: You missed the issue, and the values being compared are milliseconds since 1970-01-01 so  2012-11-10 has a greater time value than 2012-11-09.

Comment: @RobG, no I haven't miss it, I just wasn't clear. I know that it compares timestamps. I missed the missing `new` though. I thought he might have been fooled by different cultural backgrounds, because I saw many times people get confused by dates like 10/11: is it 11th Oct or 10th Nov.